# How to escape commas when pushed into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a variable that has a comma and I want to be able to contain that comma when I split my array.

```
myarray = ["hello", "apple"]
data = "Bahamas, The"
myarray << data
myarray.join(", ").split(",")
```

The last line will produce

```
["hello", " apple", " Bahamas", " The"]
```

but I want

```
["hello", " apple", " Bahamas, The"]
```

Comment: Perhaps, you could join and split by some other character? What is the point of that roundtrip, by the way?

Comment: There are no other characters that apply to values to use split on

Comment: That is in no way demonstrated by your code. In fact, I'm not even sure what that means.

Comment: how about setting data as an array? `myarray = ["hello", "apple"]` `data = "Bahamas, The"` `myarray + [data]`

Comment: @CarlMarkham: that's what he has originally, according to first three lines.

Comment: Yeah, this code already does what you want it to if you remove the last line.

Comment: @maxple: not really. It appears that he wants the weird spacing around words. Which could be accomplished by using some other char, rarer than comma. Or, you know, adding spaces directly to strings, without join/split roundtrip. Or, his actual code looks __nothing__ like this and we are being unintentionally misled.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're running into problems similar to those solved by the CSV class, so perhaps you should back up and look at how you're storing the data. You shouldn't `join` the elements then re-`split` them; Figure out a better way to hold them and only `join` them when you're ready for final output.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense but it seems to deliver what you want :

```
myarray = %w(hello apple)
data = 'Bahamas, The'
myarray << data
placeholder = '##<<$$COMMA$$>>##'
p myarray.map { |s| s.gsub(',', placeholder) }
         .join(', ')
         .split(',')
         .map { |s| s.gsub(placeholder, ',') }

#=> ["hello", " apple", " Bahamas, The"]
```

Actually, this join/split just adds a space to all the elements except the first one. So you could just write :

```
myarray = %w(hello apple)
data = 'Bahamas, The'
myarray << data

p myarray.map.with_index { |s, i| i == 0 ? s : ' ' + s }
#=> ["hello", " apple", " Bahamas, The"]
```